# React Native API request

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, api, native

I'm using Django Rest Framework in my React Native App, so I'm fetching some data, but one field of that data is a foreign key.
How can I retrieve that foreign keys data?

---

item.owner displays http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/90/ but I want it to be the owners name which I guess needs to be fetched again.

```
const renderItem = ({item}) => (
<>
  <Text>{item.owner}</Text>
  <Text>{item.title} : {item.category}</Text>
  <Image source={{uri:item.book_pic_src}} />
</>
```

Answer (score 0):

FIXED:

For anyone having the same problem, you have to send the correct data from the API. If you are using Django Rest, you have to serialize every individual object(which contains a Foreign Key) before sending it through the API.